# Extend existing entity to override add and remove functions

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to add additional logic to a 3rd party bundle entity. In this entity there are add and remove functions.

Is there a way to extend this entity and override the add and remove function?

This is my extended entity. I am try to extend `Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Entity\CalendarEvent`. When I run it, my extended entity is not called.

```html
<?php

namespace CampusCRM\CampusCalendarBundle\Entity;

use Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Entity\CalendarEvent as BaseEntity;
use Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Entity\Attendee;

class CalendarEvent extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * CalendarEvent constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

        /**
     * Add attendee of Calendar Event. This method should not be called using child event.
     *
     * @param Attendee $attendee
     * @return CalendarEvent
     * @throws \LogicException If method is called with child event.
     */
    public function addAttendee(Attendee $attendee)
    {
        parent::addAttendee($attendee);

        file_put_contents('/tmp/freq.log', 'add attendee '  . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html and update your question if you still have problems.

Comment: I have read it. I can override all other parts of the bundle, except the entity file.

Comment: Ah yes, I think you can not override the doctrine entity mapping. The [class is defined as a parameter](https://github.com/orocrm/OroCalendarBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.yml#L3) but only used in some parts. Other parts directly instantiate it, so I guess you need to override a lot of parts if you want to "swap" the class. 

Do you just need to add a log entry once an attendee is added to an event?

Comment: I don't need to change the doctrine mappings. I need to fire a function whenever attendee is added or removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hook into the process when an attendee gets added or removed, I think you need to check out the [oro_calendar.listener.calendar_event_attendees](https://github.com/orocrm/OroCalendarBundle/blob/1990d7922b1041d472c6312a94285ea16e7cb449/Resources/config/services.yml#L63) service:

```
# OroCalendarBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    oro_calendar.listener.calendar_event_attendees:
        class: Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventAttendeesListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush }
```

and the related [CalendarEventAttendeesListener](https://github.com/orocrm/OroCalendarBundle/blob/master/EventListener/CalendarEventAttendeesListener.php) class:

```
<?php

namespace Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork;

use Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Entity\Attendee;
use Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Entity\CalendarEvent;
use Oro\Bundle\PlatformBundle\EventListener\OptionalListenerInterface;

class CalendarEventAttendeesListener implements OptionalListenerInterface
{
    /** @var bool */
    protected $enabled = true;
/**
 * @param OnFlushEventArgs $args
 */
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    if (!$this->enabled) {
        return;
    }

    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
    $unitOfWork = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();

    $newEntities = $unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityInsertions();
    $updateEntities = $unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityUpdates();
    $deletedEntities = $unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityDeletions();

    foreach ($newEntities as $entity) {
        if ($this->isAttendeeApplicable($entity, $unitOfWork)) {
            $this->updateCalendarEventUpdatedAt($entity->getCalendarEvent(), $unitOfWork);
        }
    }
    foreach ($updateEntities as $entity) {
        if ($this->isAttendeeApplicable($entity, $unitOfWork)) {
            $this->updateCalendarEventUpdatedAt($entity->getCalendarEvent(), $unitOfWork);
        }
    }
    foreach ($deletedEntities as $entity) {
        if ($this->isAttendeeApplicable($entity, $unitOfWork)
            && !$unitOfWork->isScheduledForDelete($entity->getCalendarEvent())
        ) {
            $this->updateCalendarEventUpdatedAt($entity->getCalendarEvent(), $unitOfWork);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param object $entity
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function isAttendeeApplicable($entity, UnitOfWork $unitOfWork)
{
    return $entity instanceof Attendee
        && $entity->getCalendarEvent()
        && !$entity->getCalendarEvent()->isUpdatedAtSet()
        && count($unitOfWork->getEntityChangeSet($entity->getCalendarEvent())) == 0;
}

/**
 * @param CalendarEvent $calendarEvent
 * @param UnitOfWork    $unitOfWork
 */
protected function updateCalendarEventUpdatedAt(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent, UnitOfWork $unitOfWork)
{
    $oldUpdatedAt = $calendarEvent->getUpdatedAt();
    $newUpdatedAt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

    $calendarEvent->setUpdatedAt($newUpdatedAt);
    $unitOfWork->propertyChanged($calendarEvent, 'updatedAt', $oldUpdatedAt, $newUpdatedAt);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setEnabled($enabled = true)
{
    $this->enabled = $enabled;
}
```

}

Either override the `onFlush` method or create your own EventListener with a similar approach to fire your function in the process.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am looking for.